# Flutter getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() not working as expected on Android but OK on iOS/iPadOS

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator

**--- Important Update ---**

After many hours of experimenting I have found out more about what I think has changed.

As I am not very familiar with Android I had assumed (wrongly it now seems) that the Flutter build system for Android would take the necessary action on the Flutter version property in pubspec.yaml like it does for iOS, but it seems I was mistaken.

For the last 2 years I have released builds of my app where the Flutter version property has gone from '1.0.0+1' to '1.0.0+2', '1.0.0+3', '1.0.1+1', and so on up to '1.1.4+9', and everything worked as I was expecting. However, what I did not appreciate until now is that when I updated from '1.0.0+3' to '1.0.1+1' Android would have detected INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE because the versionCode for the Flutter version of my app - '1.0.1+1' - is 1 and the versionCode for the previous version of the app - '1.0.0+3' - was 3 so Android thought I was trying to downgrade from version 3 to version 1.

You can see that in the output I posted in my original question because when I try to upgrade to '1.1.5+1' from '1.1.4+9' you can see the error because 1 is less than 9:

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install /Users/les/.../build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE: Package Verification Result]
```

As far as I can see, what has changed is that until very recently "downgrading" did not remove the old app's user data and now it does but why is that so?

If this change is not an error and is deemed to be for the better does this mean that Flutter developers for both iOS and Android targets need to have different version properties for each platform or modify our Flutter generated android/app/build.gradle to calculate a useful Android versionCode from the app's Flutter version property (that is what I have opted to do to get around this problem for now).

If I have not understood what is happening here correctly then I would be very grateful if someone could explain this properly so that I can take the correct action.

Many thanks

Les.

**--- Orignal question ---**

Apologies for this long post but I have looked at all the other getApplicationDocumentsDirectory questions here and none of them seem to cover my problem and I hope that someone can help me to try and fix this.

I have been working on an app for more than a year now and had no problems until now with the app storing user generated data on their device. But now when I try to upgrade my app on Android it is unable to see any data from the previous version of the app but everything still works as usual on iOS/iPadOS!

I am using MacOS Ventura (13.6), VSCode (1.82.2) and Flutter 3.13.6 and I have two separate windows in VSCode, one for v1.1.4+9 of my app and one for v1.1.5+1 (each window is in a different git repository).

Each version has exactly the same main.dart file and here is the code that seems to be causing me the problem:

```
Future<void> main() async {
    FlutterError.onError = (FlutterErrorDetails details) async {
        final exception = details.exception;
        final stackTrace = details.stack ?? StackTrace.empty;
        if (isInDebugMode) {
            FlutterError.dumpErrorToConsole(details);
        } else {
            Zone.current.handleUncaughtError(exception, stackTrace);
        }
    };
    runZonedGuarded<Future<void>>(() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    await Hive.initFlutter(dir.path);
    // register Hive TypeAdapters for our enums...
    Hive.registerAdapter(RandomNumberTypeAdapter());
    Hive.registerAdapter(DamageTableOptionAdapter());
    Hive.registerAdapter(PilotRatingTypeAdapter());
    await openGameFiles();
    await initSettings();
```

I start a single Android emulator using either Genymotion or Android studio and then start a debug session using v1.1.4 with a breakpoint at here:

```
await Hive.initFlutter(dir.path);
```

This is so that I can look at the ApplicationDocumentsDirectory "dir" and I can see the following in the VSCode DEBUG CONSOLE:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Pixel 3 in debug mode...
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:54668/tAp30o9icjc=/ws


dir
_Directory (Directory: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter')
_path: "/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter"
_rawPath: Uint8List (43 items)
absolute: _Directory (Directory: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter')
hashCode: 925209278
isAbsolute: true
parent: _Directory (Directory: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01')
path: "/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter"
runtimeType: Type (_Directory)
uri: _Uri (file:///data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter/)


dir.listSync()
List (22 items)
[0]: _File (File: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter/mytftbox.lock')
[1]: _File (File: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter/mytftbox.hive')
[2]: _File (File: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter/cmpgn1.lock')
[3]: _File (File: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter/citye.lock')
[4]: _File (File: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter/cmpgn5.hive')
[5]: _File (File: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter/cityi.lock')
[6]: _File (File: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter/cmpgn3.hive')
[7]: _File (File: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter/cmpgn6.lock')
[8]: _File (File: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter/cmpgn2.hive')
[9]: _File (File: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter/gamebox.lock')
[10]: _File (File: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter/gamebox.hive')
[11]: _File
[12]: _Directory
[13]: _File
[14]: _File
[15]: _File
[16]: _File
[17]: _File
[18]: _File
[19]: _File
[20]: _File
[21]: _File
```

I now stop the debug session in the 1.1.4 window and start a debug session from the 1.1.5 window using the same emulator instance and the same breakpoint and this is what I see in the DEBUG CONSOLE:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Pixel 3 in debug mode...
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Uninstalling old version...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install /Users/les/.../build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE: Package Verification Result]

Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:55046/Ki5K48e3ahk=/ws


dir
_Directory (Directory: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter')
_path: "/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter"
_rawPath: Uint8List (43 items)
absolute: _Directory (Directory: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter')
hashCode: 749014032
isAbsolute: true
parent: _Directory (Directory: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01')
path: "/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter"
runtimeType: Type (_Directory)
uri: _Uri (file:///data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter/)


dir.listSync()
List (2 items)
[0]: _File (File: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter/res_timestamp-1-1696326308216')
[1]: _Directory (Directory: '/data/user/0/info.larsj.tft_01/app_flutter/flutter_assets')
```

So all the 20 user generated data files from 1.1.4 are missing

I have tried all of the following, individually and all together, and the results are always the same:

- clean both projects
- delete the android folders and then recreate them using flutter create
- flutter pub upgrade --major-versions

Note that a diff of the two pubscpec.yaml files shows the only difference to be the "version: " line (as I would expect).

My main development environment is an iMac but I also did a fresh install on a MBP 15 and the results are the same on both platforms.

Is there anything else I can try to help find out what might be causing this?

Thanks

Les

Comment: `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() not working as expected`. That function will deliver a path. If the path in both cases is the same then it works as expected and you should better describe your problem.

Comment: Thanks @blackapps but according to the docs, getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() returns a Directory object (Future<Directory> actually) and the contents of that Directory object are not what is expected. So, because calling getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() is the only way to get that Directory object I think that my description of the problem is reasonable isn't it?